# MVC HandlerError attribute isn't redirecting to error View on Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

**Question Background:**

I have a simple 'Contact Form' on my page. The user needs to supply their name, email a message subject and the actual message itself.

I'm Currently trying to implement an 'Error' View will display during any errors on the mailing process such as an incorrect email format the uer supplys.

**The Issue:**

I'm using the MVC `HandleError` attribute on my Home Controller, currently the page is not being shown when an error is thrown.

**Code:**
This is the Contact form which uses AJAX to submit the request to the Action method on the Home Controller:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SendFMFCMail", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result", OnBegin = "LoadingSpinner", OnSuccess = "MessageSent", OnFailure = "FailedMail" }))
        {
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

            <div id="result"></div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = " form-control spanWidth", placeHolder = "Name", id = "name" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
                                @*<input class="form-control spanWidth" id="name" placeholder="Name">*@
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control spanWidth", placeHolder = "Email", id = "email" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Subject, new { @class = "form-control spanWidth", placeHolder = "Subject", id = "subject" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Subject)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Message, new { @class = "form-control spanHeight spanWidth", placeHolder = "Message", rows = 15, id = "message" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block spanWidth" value="Send Message" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The `Error.cshtml` View is in the projects `Shared` folder.

I have made sure the `Web.config` has `CustomErrors` turned `On`:

```
 <customErrors mode="On" />
```

This is the `FilterConfig.cs`:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
```

In the `HomeController` I have tried setting a general exception handler at the top of the class:

```
[HandleError(View = "FMFCError")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   //code.
}
```

And I have also tried setting it on my `Action` method, which also does not work:

**Note:** I have set an explicit exception type of `SmtpException` as this is what I'm expecting to fail when an email is sent with an invalid email address;

```
[HandleError(ExceptionType = typeof(SmtpException), View = "FMFCError")]
public ActionResult SendFMFCMail(Contact contactDetails)
{

  var emailHandler = new EmailHandler();

    try
    {
        emailHandler.SendMail(contactDetails);
    }
    catch(SmtpException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    return Json(new { messageStatus = "success" });
}
```

This is the `SendMail` method:

```
public void SendMail(Contact emailMessage)
{
    string sellerEmail = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SellerEmail"];

    MailAddress from = new MailAddress(emailMessage.Email, emailMessage.Name);
    MailAddress to = new MailAddress(sellerEmail);
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, to);

    mail.Subject = emailMessage.Subject;
    mail.Body = emailMessage.Message;

    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient()
    {
        Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
        Port = 587,
        EnableSsl = true,
        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(from.Address, WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SellerEmailPassword"])
    };

    client.Send(mail);
}
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Are you using an ajax call to send the email? Please show how you are calling the SendFMFCMail function on the client side.

Comment: what does your AJAX response look like? If is an AJAX call, it will not redirect your calling page to a new page, it will just return your "FMFCError" view in the AJAX response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot redirect via an AJAX post. You can send back the URL to the frontend to which you want to redirect the browser to and then use JS to navigate there.

Backend - Home Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GoToMethodName()
{ 
     return Json(Url.Action("Index", "MethodName"));   
}
```

Views JS - This is simple code that assumes you will redirect on exception or success, more complex logic handling can be written depending on how you would like to handle the success, this will fix your redirect on exception caught needs.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/GoToMethodName",
        dataType: 'json',
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function(data){
            window.location.href = data;
        }
    });
```